# Adding back removed action, based on custom meta data wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to do is

1. Input an custom URL from user, save it as product meta.
2. If there is an URL set, not empty, then remove add_to_cart button and place in button with custom link.
3. If not, add an fall-back to show add to cart button and variations same as it used to be.

Now here is how code looks -

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_remove_add_to_cart')); // Goes in class constructor.

function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_remove_add_to_cart() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );

        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button'), 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button'), 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button'), 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button'), 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', array($this, 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button'), 30 );
    }

function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button() {
        global $post,$product;
        if($this->woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_get_cartURL() !='')
        echo '<form name="custom_cart_button" method="post" action="'.$this->woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_get_cartURL().'"><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">'.$this->woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_get_carttext().'</button></form><br />';
        else {
            // What logic should go here to handle the fall back, and show the default add to cart button. adding the actions wont work.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the remove_action and add_action code to another hook where you will get the Product ID such as "woocommerce_before_single_product_summary" and check your condition inside it, if it matches then remove default woocommerce hooks and add your hooks.

And do not remove the hook **"woocommerce_single_product_summary -> woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart"** and add it back since it is not needed.

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_single_product_summary", "test_func");
    function test_func(){
        global $post,$product;
        if( TEST-CONDITION ){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button', 30 );
        }
    }
    function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_custom_button() {
        global $post,$product;
        echo '<form name="custom_cart_button" method="post" action="REQUIRED_URL"><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">BUTTON TEXT</button></form><br />';
    }
```